# Захват UTM меток в динамическую ссылку на сайт

Tags: php, wordpress

Друзья, исполнитель написал плагин для сайта на wordpress, но забыл захватить помимо url страницы входа UTM метку, а она является основной частью тз.
Подскажите, что добавить в этот кусок, чтобы пробрасывалась сама метка?

```
 // Generate the dynamic link URL
    $url = 'SITE_NAME'; // Replace with the target site URL
    $dynamic_link = add_query_arg(array(
        'campaign' => $campaign,
        'user' => $user,
    ), $url);
```

Кусок с функционалом, для расширения контекста

```
    function generate_dynamic_link() { 
        // Check if the 'campaign' parameter is present in the URL         
        if (isset($_GET['utm_source'])) { 
            $campaign = sanitize_text_field($_GET['utm_source']); 
        } else { 
            // If 'utm_source' is not present, use the Referer header as the campaign value 
            $campaign = sanitize_text_field($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); 
        if ( empty( $campaign ) ) { 
            $campaign = 'SITE_NAME.ru'; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: function generate_dynamic_link() {
    // Check if the 'campaign' parameter is present in the URL
    if (isset($_GET['utm_source'])) {
        $campaign = sanitize_text_field($_GET['utm_source']);
    } else {
        // If 'utm_source' is not present, use the Referer header as the campaign value
        $campaign = sanitize_text_field($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  if ( empty( $campaign ) ) {
   $campaign = 'SITE_NAME.ru';
  }
    Кусок с функционалом, для расширения контекста

Comment: Если Я правильно понял таску, то сам параметр уже проверенный и пробросить `'utm_param'=>$_GET['utm_param'] ?? false`

Comment: Добавить это в первый блок?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы попробовал сделать вот так:

```php
$dynamic_link = add_query_arg(array(
    'campaign' => $campaign,
    'user' => $user,
    'utm_source' => 'google';
), $url);
```

Где google нужно будет заменить на нужный [по примеру из генератора](https://tilda.cc/ru/utm/).